# problem with getting data from database

Tags: c#, .net, sql, winforms, dataset

I am trying to get the  data from database by using the below code.....

if there is no data in the table it will always goes to 
this statement

I am using mysql.net connector for getting the data and i am doing winforms  applications
using c#

```
     public DataTable sales(DateTime startdate, DateTime enddate)
     {
         const string sql = @"SELECT memberAccTran_Source as Category, sum(memberAccTran_Value) as Value
                              FROM memberacctrans
                              WHERE memberAccTran_DateTime BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
                              GROUP BY memberAccTran_Source";

         return sqlexecution(startdate, enddate, sql);
     }
```

and the below code is for return sqlexceution...function..

```
 private static DataTable sqlexecution(DateTime startdate, DateTime enddate, string sql)
 {
         var table = new DataTable();
         using (var conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
         {
             conn.Open();

             var cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(sql, conn);

             var ds = new DataSet();

             var parameter = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@startdate", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.DateTime);
             parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
             parameter.Value = startdate.ToString(dateformat);
             cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

             var parameter2 = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@enddate", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.DateTime);
             parameter2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
             parameter2.Value = enddate.ToString(dateformat);
             cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter2);

             var da = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

             da.Fill(ds);
             try
             {
                 table = ds.Tables[0];

             }
             catch
             {
                 table = null;
             }
         }
         return table;
     }
```

even if there is no data the process flow will goes to this line

> table = ds.Tables[0];

how can i reduce this .....

would any one pls help on this....

Comment: Have you considered using an ORM e.g. Linq to SQL Entities or EF?

Comment: no.. i have to use this one ....

Comment: The Try {} statement only executes catch {} if the assignment throws an exception. Why should it? If the result data set is empty, it still will have one result table with 0 rows. No?

Comment: Try using the builtin debugger to see what property values the ds and especially ds.Tables[0] contain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case if you are think that catch block will get excuted if there is no row available than you are wrong because Even if there is no data once select query is get exucuted without exception it Creates datatable with the columns but with no rows.

for this i think you can make use of `ds.table[0].rows.count` property which return 0 if there is no row in datatable.

```
if ( ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 )
     table = ds.Tables[0];
else
     table=null;
```

Comment: The DataTable's Rows property is null when there are no rows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.datatable.rows.aspx

Comment: @Stuart Dunkeld  - its better you run the code and check it out by your self and if possible remove your downvote once you done with the checking

Comment: @Stuart Dunkeld  - its not misleading read the answer i wrote when you fill data from using select statement it creates table with no row if there is no row exists that means you need to check row count for checking no of rows

Comment: Documentation is somewhat misleading. Apologies.

Answer (score 3):

It returns an empty table. This is common behavior. If you want to have table null you should check for the row count :

```
If ( ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count >. 0 )
     table = ds.Tables[0];
Else
     table=0
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure what you're asking here ... I assume you want it to skip the table = ds.tables[0] line if there is no data?

if thats the case a try/catch wont work as it wont throw an exception ... try something like this instead ...

```
if(ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count >0)
{
    table = ds.Tables[0];
}
else
{
    table = null;
}
```